# How can I integrate a prefix checker to find complete words based on file read

Tags: c, recursion, prefix

**ISSUE:** I'm able to search through the file and print words based on numbers entered by the user (text-message number conversion), buy I should also be able to find full words based on only a portion of the numbers entered, so ... `72` would return pa, ra, sa, and sc... which would find words in my file such as `party`, `radio`, `sandwich`, and `scanner`.

I've tried utilizing prefix functions, but I'm unable to integrate them properly. The `startsWith` function is an example.

The words are based on a numbered keypad such as: [Lettered Phone Keypad](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Telephone-keypad2.svg/1200px-Telephone-keypad2.svg.png&imgrefurl=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad&h=973&w=1200&tbnid=QrUdyaA0gSl_YM:&q=phone%20keypad%20letters&tbnh=160&tbnw=197&usg=AI4_-kQ3l4j1JO1ANHzT5LGipsxuDvvilg&vet=1&docid=RxQBHK3rnZZ3dM&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiamY3WktTeAhVPm-AKHcpBB38Q9QEwAHoECAUQBg)

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


const char numbered_letters[10][5] = {"", "", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl",
                                      "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"};



bool startsWith(const char *pre, const char *str) {
    size_t lenpre = strlen(pre),
            lenstr = strlen(str);
    return lenstr < lenpre ? false : strncmp(pre, str, lenpre) == 0;
}

void isEqual(char input[]) {
    int i = 0;
    //input[strlen(input)] = 0;
    startsWith(input, input);
    printf("check:  %s\n", input);
    //creating file
    FILE *fp = fopen("words_alpha.txt", "r");
    char str[32]; /* Handles largest possible string in the list which is: dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane*/
    //fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error! No file!\n");
    } else {
        //printf("Enter a number to be converted into a word-list");
        //scanf("%s", str);

        while (!feof(fp)) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
            i = strncmp(input, str, 32);
            if (i == 0) {
                printf("HIT:    %s \n", input);
                break;
            } else {
                printf("");
            }
            //if (strncmp(str, "hello", 32 ) == 0) { /*if strncmp finds the word and returns true, print */
            //  printf("%s\n", str);

        }
        //printf("%s\n", str);
        //compareNums(num);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}


void printWordsUtil(int number[], int curr_digit, char output[], int n) {

    // Base case, if current output word is prepared
    int i;
    if (curr_digit == n) {
        //printf("%s ", output);
        isEqual(output);
        return;

    }

    // Try all possible characters for current digit in number[]
    // and recur for remaining digits
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(numbered_letters[number[curr_digit]]); i++) {

        output[curr_digit] = numbered_letters[number[curr_digit]][i];
        printWordsUtil(number, curr_digit + 1, output, n);/* recursive call */


        if (number[curr_digit] == 0 || number[curr_digit] == 1)
            return;
    }
}

// A wrapper over printWordsUtil().  It creates an output array and
// calls printWordsUtil()
void printWords(int number[], int n) {
    char result[n + 1];
    result[n] = '\0';

    printWordsUtil(number, 0, result, n);


}

//Driver program
int main(void) {
    int number[] = {4, 3, 9};
    int n = sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0]);
    printWords(number, n);
    return 0;
}
```

**FILE USED:** [Words Alpha (A file with over 420k words)](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words_alpha.txt)

Thank you for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: I don't get it. Whats the relation of `72` to `"pa"`, `"ra"`, `"sa"`, and `"sc"`?

Comment: I apologize, should've been more clear. The numbers are based on the numbers on a keypad (see the top has a constant 2D char array, with each number having a value of letters. So the recursion searches through possibilities and then compares those to words in the file, otherwise it would return a mess of letter combinations that have no place in the english language. I will place a keypad in the post to clear things up. @Swordfish

Comment: So you're essentially talking about [T9 texting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T9_(predictive_text))?

Comment: That `fscanf(fp, "%s"` and `while (!feof(fp)` look bad, just use `while (fgets(str, 32, fp))`. So `isEqual` is recursively called from `printWordsUtil` with all the permutations obtained from `439` number? Your `startpre` once you know that `lenstr > lenpre` you can just `memcmp(pre, str, lenpre) == 0` would save few cycles.

Comment: When you start looking for efficient, fast, prefix searching, an optimal solution is a [Ternary Search Tree for Prefix-Search](https://github.com/drankinatty/ternary_st). The examples there will use your `words_alpha.txt` loading all 370099 words in 0.176696 sec. You can then prefix search, e.g. finding all 275 words beginning with `"zoo"` in  0.000064 sec.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin did you happen to create that algorithm?

Comment: No. I heard about the algorithm and was intrigued by the memory saving it allowed compared to a traditional TRIE tree. So I went looking for more information and examples -- there were very few. I could find a basic example on filling a ternary tree -- but no examples handled deletion properly. So the deletion rotation part of the algorithm is mine, but the concept of the ternary tree isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few bugs.

Your prefix function was okay. The `strncmp` you replaced it with was not.

You had a `break` on a hit that stopped on the *first* word match, so subsequent ones were not shown.

On a hit you were printing the prefix string instead of the word string.

I've annotated your code with the bugs and fixed them [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const char numbered_letters[10][5] = { "", "", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl",
    "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"
};

bool
startsWith(const char *pre, const char *str)
{
    size_t lenpre = strlen(pre),
        lenstr = strlen(str);

    return lenstr < lenpre ? false : strncmp(pre, str, lenpre) == 0;
}

void
isEqual(char input[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int ilen = strlen(input);

    // input[strlen(input)] = 0;
// NOTE/BUG: this is extraneous
#if 0
    startsWith(input, input);
#endif
    printf("check:  '%s'\n", input);

    // creating file
    FILE *fp = fopen("words_alpha.txt", "r");
// NOTE/BUG: this needs to be one more to contain the nul terminater
#if 0
    /* Handles largest possible string in the list which is:
        dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane */
    char str[32];
#else
    char str[33];
#endif

    // fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error! No file!\n");
    }
    else {
        // printf("Enter a number to be converted into a word-list");
        // scanf("%s", str);

// NOTE/BUG: although feof works here, it is considered _bad_ practice
#if 0
        while (!feof(fp)) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
#else
        while (1) {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != 1)
                break;
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: this is broken
#if 0
            i = strncmp(input, str, 32) == 0;
#endif
// NOTE: this works and is simpler than startsWith (which also works)
#if 0
            i = strncmp(input, str, ilen) == 0;
#endif
#if 1
            i = startsWith(input, str);
#endif

            if (i) {
// NOTE/BUG: we want the actual word to be printed and not just the prefix
#if 0
                printf("HIT:    %s\n", input);
#else
                printf("HIT:    %s\n", str);
#endif
// NOTE/BUG: this break stops on the _first_ word match in the list but we
// want all of them
#if 0
                break;
#endif
            }
            else {
                //printf("");
            }
            // if (strncmp(str, "hello", 32 ) == 0) { /*if strncmp finds the word and returns true, print */
            // printf("%s\n", str);

        }
        // printf("%s\n", str);
        // compareNums(num);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void
printWordsUtil(int numbers[], int curr_digit, char output[], int n)
{

    // Base case, if current output word is prepared
    int i;

    if (curr_digit == n) {
        // printf("%s ", output);
        isEqual(output);
        return;
    }

// NOTE: did some cleanup to understand what was going on -- [probably] not a
// bug
    int numcur = numbers[curr_digit];
    const char *letters = numbered_letters[numcur];
    int letlen = strlen(letters);

    // Try all possible characters for current digit in number[]
    // and recur for remaining digits
    for (i = 0; i < letlen; ++i) {
        output[curr_digit] = letters[i];
        printWordsUtil(numbers, curr_digit + 1, output, n); /* recursive call */
        if ((numcur == 0) || (numcur == 1))
            break;
    }
}

// A wrapper over printWordsUtil().  It creates an output array and
// calls printWordsUtil()
void
printWords(int number[], int n)
{
    char result[n + 1];

// NOTE/BUG: this will have garbage in elements 0 to (n - 1)
// NOTE/BUG: result is not used otherwise
    result[n] = '\0';

    printWordsUtil(number, 0, result, n);

}

//Driver program
int
main(void)
{
    int number[] = { 4, 3, 9 };
    int n = sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0]);

    printWords(number, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you intent to not comment on [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin hey again David!! Hope you're having a good day!

Comment: Yep, day is going well. Keep at it, but don't rush There is a lot to digest. The approach to learning C is a lot like the approach to eating a whale -- you got to take it one bite (or byte) at a time `:)`

Comment: @Craig-Estey, first I'd like to thank you for finding those bugs and solving my issue... I wanted to ask why you use `#if` style instead of the standard syntax? I've just never seen that before, thought it was pretty cool. Thanks again!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin haha you're quickly becoming an inspiration to me!

Comment: The `#if #else #endif` (you will also see `#ifdef` (short for `#if defined`), etc..) which are *preprocessor* directives. In these cases they simply provide a way to choose which code to use at compile time by either setting a `#define` on the command line with `-DYOURTAG` or defining it in your code manually. So if I had alternate code that would execute `#ifdef YOURTAG`, I could pass `-DYOURTAG` as part of the compiler options to make that test true and include the code between `#ifdef YOURTAG ... #endif`. You will see that used in many sources.

Comment: @user7823016 `#if 0` is a debugging thing [usually temporarily]. Wrapping code with `#if 0` to "comment" it out is better than doing `/* ... some_code ... */`. I use it to nullify "suspect" code without actually removing it (e.g. the code _might_ actually be correct which I find out later and I just do `#if 1`). When fully debugged, I clean up the `#if 0/1` blocks. Here, I use `#if 0` to show _your_ code vs. the corrected code (e.g. like the output of `diff` [sort of])

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi, David. Actually, I saw the `feof` and was going comment on it and to edit it out. Usually, I post an annotated version [with minimal changes] and a cleaned up version [which has more style cleanups and refactoring]. Here, I was pressed for time, so I just did the first version. Since you've posted the link [and properly admonished me :-)], I just updated the code to put `#if 0` around the `feof` code`

Comment: Yes, I caught that. Always a good opportunity to point out "Don't do that!" to the questioner to make sure he (or she) doesn't continue to repeat the error. It was a good and helpful answer with the bonus of an introduction to preprocessor directives as well `:)`